# Test for async property in script tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In an rspec feature test, I want to test for the presence of the following code

```
<script src="/assets/application.js" async="async"></script>
```

If I try

```
page.should have_css 'script', src: "/assets/application.js", async: 'async'
```

I get an error message that `:src, :async` are invalid keys. I want to use the test to make sure that on heroku the `application.js` file is loaded asynchronously.

How do I test for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of issues: Firstly, by default, Capybara doesn't find elements that aren't visible (this includes script tags).  Secondly :src and :async aren't things Capybara knows anything about.  The solution to this is to include the src and async requirements in the css selector, and pass the `visible: false` options so Capybara will find non-visible elements.

```
page.should have_css('script[async="async"][src="/assets/application.js"]', visible: false)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, and the ```visible: false``` tip will be useful in lots of other places.